# How to share array memory between JavaScriptCore and Swift?

Tags: swift, memory, javascriptcore

I am trying to write a Swift program that runs JS via JavaScriptCore. I wish to share memory between both parts of my program such that the JS writes to a typed array buffer created in Swift, and Swift reads and writes to it afterwards. This will be a sort of command buffer.

For example, here is some pseudocode that approximately represents what I'm planning to do:

```
// js
let buf;
let i = 0;
setup() {
   buf = new Uint8Array(mem.alloc(N_BYTES));
}

frame() {
   i = 0;
   buf[i++] = some_command_enum;
}

// swift
func alloc(bytes : Int) -> the_memory {
    // allocate bytes uints and save the memory here
    // save a reference to the memory here
    // return the memory to use in JS
}
```

The problem is that whenever I try actually adding the implementation to alloc, JS reports via exception that the function is undefined, meaning that something is off with the way I'm doing things. Non-returning functions are fine, so I have that down.

This is my faulty implementation (please see the comments):

```swift
// swift
@objc protocol JSMemoryExports: JSExport {
    static func alloc(_ byte_count: Int) -> JSObjectRef
    static func free(_ memory: JSObjectRef)
}

class JSMemory: NSObject, JSMemoryExports {
                                           // What is the correct return type?
    class func alloc(_ byte_count: Int) -> JSObjectRef {
        // temp
        let jsContext = JS_Controller.js.ctx!

        print("BYTE_COUNT", byte_count)

        // allocating a typed array
        let arr = JSObjectMakeTypedArray(jsContext.jsGlobalContextRef!, kJSTypedArrayTypeUint8Array, byte_count, nil)

        // just testing here to see how I'd write to this buffer (Note: is this the fastest way, or is all this memory binding slow?:
        // getting the raw bytes
        let ptr = JSObjectGetTypedArrayBytesPtr(jsContext.jsGlobalContextRef!, arr, nil)
        //let buf = JSObjectGetTypedArrayBuffer(jsContext.jsGlobalContextRef, arr, nil)
        let u8Ptr = ptr!.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: byte_count)
        //u8Ptr[0] = 5
        return arr!
    }
}

...

jsContext["mem"] = JSMemory.self
```

```js
// js
const buf = new Uint8Array(mem.alloc(8)) // JS Exception: TypeError: mem.alloc is not a function. (In 'mem.alloc(8)', 'mem.alloc' is undefined)
```

I've seen variants of function binding that uses some sort of `@convention` attribute. Am I meant to use that instead?

What is the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation isn't very helpful unless you piece together a lot of information from separate sources. The seemingly working solution involves using parts of the older C API that are callable in Swift, unsafe pointers, and making sure the return values of the bound functions are `JSValue?`s. That makes sense since JavaScript functions all return an object, `null`, *or* `undefined`. An optional type mirrors this behavior.

Here is my work-in-progress code for anyone who might need some leads:

Just for an update, I've figured out how to mix the old C API with the new more limited Swift-specific APIs. I haven't yet made sure I'm not leaking memory, but it looks like I've found what I needed, hopefully.

In case you ever wanted to know:

```swift
@objc protocol JSMemoryExports: JSExport {
    // note that I'm returning an optional
    static func Uint8ArrayMake(_ count : JSValue) -> JSValue?
}

class JSMemory: NSObject, JSMemoryExports { 
    class func UInt8ArrayMake(_ count : JSValue) -> JSValue? {
        guard !count.isUndefined && !count.isNull else {
            return nil
        }

        let ref : JSValueRef = JSObjectMakeTypedArray(
            JS_Controller.js.ctx.jsGlobalContextRef!,
            kJSTypedArrayTypeUint8Array,
            Int(count.toInt32()),
            nil
        )!

        // if you want to modify the data
        // let ptr = JSObjectGetTypedArrayBytesPtr(
        //    JS_Controller.js.ctx.jsGlobalContextRef!, ref, nil
        // )

        return JSValue(jsValueRef: ref, in: JS_Controller.js.ctx)    
    }
}
```

Here are a couple helpful references:

[pointers in Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7181017-unsafe-swift-using-pointers-and-interacting-with-c)
[manual memory management in Swift](https://medium.com/@shoheiyokoyama/manual-memory-management-in-swift-c31eb20ea8f)